# Unexpected Sinon.js behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I'm trying to stub the [Stripe](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) module for unit testing using [Mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha) and [Sinon.js](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon).

I require Stripe like this :

```
const stripe = require('stripe');
const stubbedStripeClient = stripe.Stripe('test');
```

At the root of my tests (inside my top-level `describe()`) I have this :

```
before('stub root', () => {
  sinon.stub(stripe, 'Stripe').returns(stubbedStripeClient);
});
```

Then, in the `describe()` block where I actually would call a Stripe method, I have this `before()` hook :

```
let stub;
before('stub', () => {
  console.log(typeof stubbedStripeClient.customers.create);
  stub = sinon.stub(stubbedStripeClient.customers, 'create', ({id: 'a-stripe-customer-id'}));
});
```

This is where I don't understand what happens. The first line in the hook (`console.log`) outputs:

> function

The second line throws this exception :

> TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property create as function

How is this possible? How can it be a function on one line and be undefined on the very next line?

I looked at the Sinon.js source, and this check is performed [here](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/6b13ed766b844a15fe7fd03bedd289e4fa6e84eb/lib/sinon/util/core/wrap-method.js#L35). If I then look at their [`isFunction`](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/6b13ed766b844a15fe7fd03bedd289e4fa6e84eb/lib/sinon/util/core/wrap-method.js#L8) function, it performs the same check I have in my `console.log`. I'm puzzled.

Comment: One clue, the 3rd argument to your stub call is not a function but an object. [Looks like](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/) it needs to be a function.

Comment: Oh wow. I actually hoped it was not the solution, but it indeed works now... I really needed an external look on this, I just forgot the `() =>` to declare a function, so instead I was, as you said, passing a plain object as the third parameter. The error message however was not very clear :/ Thanks a lot @Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an unfortunate and misleading error message.

The 3rd argument to the stub call is not a function but an object. From [the docs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/) it needs to be a function.

To resolve, change:

```
({id: 'a-stripe-customer-id'})
```

to something like:

```
() => { return {id: 'a-stripe-customer-id'}; }
```

...if you want to return that object, or perhaps you meant the object as a parameter:

```
({id: 'a-stripe-customer-id'}) => {}
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem. The third parameter was supposed to be a function that return the `{id: 'a-stripe-customer-id'}` object. I simply forgot the `() =>` in front of it. However in my case the `.returns()` would have been more appropriate than the third argument, and would not have led to this error